# How do I place top slabs using the /fill command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to place hundreds of blocks and I do that easily with the fill command. But, I can't seem to fill an area with top slabs. I tried `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:stone_slab` then I get bottom slabs placed.

Answer (score 13):

In the 1.13 snapshot, use `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:oak_slab[type=top]`.

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is that the command
`/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:stone_slab` automatically means `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:stone_slab 0`, the 0 is added. If you change this 0 to another value, the slab will change it's position; 8 is for the upper stone slabs:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:stone_slab 8
```

**Note:** This technique works only for Minecraft versions 1.12.2 and older. For newer versions, check out the other answer on this question.

Comment: @NabeelParkar If this answer solved your problem, hit the check mark. It rewards the answerer, and tells future visitors what solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way that you would do this is by using a square bracket at the end of your block type. If you want top slabs, it would be executed as `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:stone_slab[type=top]`. If you want to find out some more things about /fill, this video will hopefully help:

Answer (score 1):

As for top slabs, you can pretty much just tab the thing ingame. I did, and it worked out:

`/fill {coördinates} {coördinates} minecraft:stone_slab[type=top]`

I just tabbed in the command itself, but now you know it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers posted here work for me (Minecraft Bedrock 1.16+).  I was searching forever to get this to work for me.  I finally figured it out, and is kind of tricky.  The various "original" stone slabs(stonebrick, andesite, cobble, etc.) are broken down into 4 groups(stone_slab, stone_slab2, etc.).  There is an additional data value you need to get more specific(top, double)

This will give you mossy stone brick bottom slabs

- `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 stone_slab4`

Whereas this will give you regular stone top slabs

- `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 stone_slab4 10`

Use the various information in the [slab article wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slab) to help build your command.  Took me a lot of tries to get the regular stone upper slabs.  The "Double Upper" used in the article is kind of a bad label as it seems to refer to the single upper slabs instead of 2 slabs together.

Comment: As much as I appreciate you taking your time to figure your problem out yourself, the answers here aren't incorrect. since the question is tagged `minecraft-java-edition`. If you want, you can "ask" a new question regarding the same issue but for bedrock edition and answer it yourself to help others with your issue.

Comment: For my part, I am glad you posted this, because this page is the first search result for "bedrock fill bottom slab". It is what I was looking for, so I upvoted your answer. With the efforts underway to merge Bedrock and Java features, your answer should also apply to Java (but I have no idea if it does). And @Quijibo nobody said the answers here are incorrect. They just don't work for Bedrock. And that matters a lot, because Bedrock has the larger installed base.

Answer (score -2):

I'm just going to be really straightforward, `/fill x y z x y z slab ["top_slot_bit" : true ]` NOTE: I do not know if this works for java edition, nor do I know if this works for lower versions (1.19 and below) This only for sure works on 1.20 bedrock edition

Comment: Please read the tags of the question and don't post answers for other editions.